# How to add class "is-invalid" in an input error in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x, form-helpers

I'm trying to put the .is-invalid class in my input to use the bootstrap css...
But I only have "inputContainerError"

```
'inputContainerError' => '<div class="mb-3"> {{content}}{{error}}</div>',
```

Does cakephp have no "inputError" in FormHelper?

Example:

```
'inputError' => '<input type="{{type}}" class="form-control is-invalid" name="{{name}}"{{attrs}}/>'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such template, no (the available templates can be found in [**the API docs**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#%24_defaultConfig)).

Adding the `is-invalid` class is easy enough though, you'd just have to change the form helper's `errorClass` configuration:

```
$this->Form->setConfig('errorClass', 'is-invalid');
```

Adding further (static) classes is equally simple, just use the `control()` method's `class` option:

```
$this->Form->control('field', ['class' => 'form-control']);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Input Elements > Creating Text Inputs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-text-inputs)**
- **[API > \Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper:$_defaultConfig](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.View.Helper.FormHelper.html#%24_defaultConfig)**
- **[FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/bootstrap-ui/)**